# Whats the difference between TTF & OTF font files?

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

Is there a difference in load time or quality or anything like that? I just downloaded some fonts for my site, and am wondering if there's any reasons I should use one type over the other. Basically, what would you suggest using?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/96390/difference-between-otf-open-type-or-ttf-true-type-font-formats

Comment: There are loads of posts, articles, and even SO and SE questions about this already. Any web search will find you more than you will want to read to find the answer to this.

Comment: @pvg not exactly a good link these days, given how much the OpenType spec has consolidated over the last 5 years (that answer still mentions type1, for instance. Type1 fonts are extinct these days; Adobe even ported their entire collection to modern OpenType with CFF fonts years ago)

Comment: That's probably technically correct (the best kind of correct!) but the gist of the answer is still most likely right.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so which one do _you_ suggest??

Comment: @pvg: not really, that answer explains it as if ttf are "truetype" and otf are "opentype", when both .ttf and .otf files are OpenType fonts.

Comment: @FlockaFrank [Take your pick](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+otf+and+tt). Bonus points for reputable sources like adobe, typekit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So you can check the same question on Graphic Design https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/whats-the-difference-between-opentype-vs-truetype

For me this post from Typekit is a good starter https://blog.typekit.com/2010/12/02/the-benefits-of-opentypecff-over-truetype/

> OpenType/CFF (.otf file extension) and TrueType (.ttf file extension*) are the two modern font formats available for desktop usage today. Despite being distinct formats, OT/CFF and TT fonts actually have a lot in common. They are distinguished primarily by their different outline formats and the contrasting approaches employed to rasterize those outlines.

I would also recommend to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM5tN88CX30 (5 common misconceptions about OpenType vs TrueType)

I prefer OpenType as it's newer and it's updated regularly with new features, like color fonts or variable fonts for example.
OpenType has advanced typographic features (ligatures, alternate character forms, small caps ...).